# Best way to make use of Server side rendering

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router, next.js

I would like to learn Server side rendering and while searching in google,i've seen many topics about a framwork called `nextjs`,and after trying it,i found it pretty good.SO now i would take a serious course on SSR,but after a search on [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com) I've found a course which is rated `4.7/5` of `Stephen Grider`,but in the course content i've not seen `next.js`.Here is the course link : [Server Side Rendering with React and Redux](https://www.udemy.com/server-side-rendering-with-react-and-redux/).

I don't have much experience with `SSR`,but it seems that there are two ways to make it:With `React,redux,node/express` or `Next.js`.
When i've tried `next.js`,i've not used `react-router` but in the description of the courses of udemy,the instructor talks about using `react router`. 
I really need your advices before i learn it seriously,and i need to know the best solution between the 2 approches.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the different between react-router and Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53500732/whats-the-different-between-react-router-and-next-js)

Comment: A plus to the answer I submitted below, I can happily be available to check-in again with you when you finally pick a choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have done a very good research, the two options you have stated in your post are mainly the best available ones out there.

To me, if I am starting a new project, I would love to do it with React, Redux and Express.js instead of using Next.js

It will remove the complixity of learning a new thing, which is the first plus of picking that up.

I had to migrate a living 2y'o project to Next.js, the structure was a little bit not-expected for me, the routing system kinda sucked at the beginning of it, persisting layouts around the app was tiresome, forgetting about `react-router` was painful too.

In the course, I guess Stephen is welling to do client-side routing via `react-router` and implement something like `express` at the `server-side` to do SSR, I don't believe that will make it any easier.

While am saying that, it was very a interesting experience that I have gained doing the `Next.js` migration, I've learned a lot about SEO and SSR because of the troubles I had to run through.

I learnt to be careful about what should I use building my components and where should I use them, what packages can harm my app and what buggy bugs can prevent it from doing a correct SSR.

The smartest pick you can choose is sticking with React, Redux and Node/Express stack, instead of shifting -away- to Next.js

I have seen the contributors there doing a very great work, but, maybe am not yet sure how long they can survive!

Sorry for not being obvious on anything, just wanted to share what I thought.